# Import Compiler Warnings in SonarQube

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, sonar-runner, sonarqube

I have a compiler-warnings log from a JVM and I would like to import them in SonarQube labeled as issues.
For example I was able to import UnitTests coverage files with the property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath=[path]'. I wanted to ask if there is something similar for compiler-warnings.

Can anybody help me here because I did not find any help on Internt research.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is feasible. You need to write your own plugin to do that